# mysql Like ambiguios result

Tags: mysql

I have two tables a and b.

Table a has a field named gr which can have multiple values concatained with string.

Table b holds it seperately in fields lg.

How do i run the below query to check whether b.lg is in a.gr?

now b.lg has values me,me01,me02 and a.gr has to be checked agianst me02.

But the error here is that the three as matched with this

```
SELECT lg 
FROM a, b 
WHERE a.id = 22 AND  
      a.gr LIKE CONCAT('%', b.lg, '%');
```

a.gr example values

1. 'm301,you,weall'
2. 'me,you,me2'
3. 'me'

b.lg value

1.'m301'

2.'you'

3.'weall'

4.'me2'

5.'me'

6.'me1'

Comment: a.id=22 have which value? me02

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`LOCATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_locate) or `FIND_IN_SET` functions. LOCATE will find partial matches; for example it will find a match for `me` in `me1,me2`. If this is not what you want, maybe you are looking for `FIND_IN_SET`.

```
SELECT lg 
FROM a, b 
WHERE a.id = 22 AND  
      LOCATE(b.lg, a.gr) > 0;
```

Replicating the data you have posted this is the output from the SELECT:

```
mysql> create temporary table a (gr varchar(100));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.36 sec)

mysql> create temporary table b (lg varchar(100));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.08 sec)

mysql> insert into a values ('m301,you,weall'),('me,you,me2'),('me');
Query OK, 3 rows affected (0.11 sec)
Records: 3  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> insert into b values ('m301'),('you'),('weall'),('me2'),('me'),('me1');
Query OK, 6 rows affected (0.06 sec)
Records: 6  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT lg, gr  FROM a, b WHERE locate(lg,gr) > 0;
+-------+----------------+
| lg    | gr             |
+-------+----------------+
| m301  | m301,you,weall |
| you   | m301,you,weall |
| you   | me,you,me2     |
| weall | m301,you,weall |
| me2   | me,you,me2     |
| me    | me,you,me2     |
| me    | me             |
+-------+----------------+
7 rows in set (0.02 sec)
```

Comment: still the same output is coming

Comment: Please post sample of expected output.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using the [`FIND_IN_SET()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) function to join the two tables.

Try something like this:

```
select b.lg
from a
inner join b on find_in_set(b.lg,a.gr) > 0
where a.id = 22;
```

Comment: In that case you should update your question, because `FIND_IN_SET()` is exactly what is needed to "check whether b.lg is in a.gr", which is what you asked.